# django how to display a tag only if the value coming from the database is not null?

Tags: django, django-templates

**The logic for showing a tag**

```
{% if profile.facebook is not None %}<i class="facebook icon"></i>{% endif %}
```

i want to show the facebook icon only when the user has provided the link. if not i dont want to display the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your conditional as well:

```
{% if profile.facebook %}
    <i class="facebook icon"></i>
{% endif %}
```

if your code not work, you can share more info, like your views.py etc.